# Can I Use Less Oil In Shrimp Fried Rice?

Tags: oil, asian-cuisine, recipe-changing

I want to try making [this recipe](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/272834/easy-homemade-shrimp-fried-rice/) for my family - however, my wife has a sensitive stomach and I'm worried that the 4 tablespoons of oil this calls for will be excessive.

Can I instead use 2 tablespoons of oil to achieve the same result?  Will it be enough to cook the recipe?  Or is 4 tablespoons of oil really necessary for this kind of cooking?

Comment: look on youtube for a recipe (fried rice's vary greatly and being able to see the process will be very beneficial and allow you to pick one that looks like the type you are going for). Regardless, the one you picked is terrible.  Olive oil for fried rice are you joking.  And keep in mind if you want it to taste anything like takeout, well they use tons of oil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll still be able to cook this successfully using only two tbsp of oil total. The texture of the final dish will suffer slightly, being stickier and less sumptuous. Make your rice at least a couple of hours in advance.

Comment: Yes and in any recipe, why not just try changing this, that or the other? If it goes horribly wrong, how many meals might be ruined?

Comment: Also, I would swap out the sesame oil/olive oil for a lighter, more neutral oil like sunflower.  Those are terriblie oils to use for fried rice anyways.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Would Vegetable Oil do better? That, Olive Oil and Sesame are really all we've got.

Comment: @Zibbobz vegetable will be fine for this application. It's usually a blend of rapeseed (canola), soybean and sunflower or something similar, so quite neutral. Olive oil imparts a strong flavour that doesn't go well with most Asian dishes. Most sesame oil is toasted and imparts a burned flavour if used for cooking with - use it as a finisher for a nutty flavour. Light sesame oil is fine for cooking/frying generally.